# iOS globally accessible current User?

Tags: ios, authentication, core-data

What is the best practice for having globally (e.g. from all view controllers) accessible current User object?

I am using core Data.

EDIT:

I just realized I should elaborate a bit (and immediately received a comment regarding that)..

current User means the user who is the owner of the phone and is associated with an entry in the remote database. User enters login/password (or registers) and then can access the remote server, get data etc..

Comment: What is a current User object?

Comment: just added the details thanks )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Object visibility is a major part of app architecture. It is up to you to make your objects visible to the other objects that may need a reference to it. No simple rule can be given. I have tips in my book on how to make objects visible in an absolutely global way:

http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch13.html#_global_visibility

For example, store a reference in the app delegate, which every other object can easily get a reference to. But there are lots of other solutions and approaches (which that chapter also talks about). It's a matter of planning ahead.